# How to display WooCommerce product not on sale?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to Display Product which are not sale means only regular product. Exclude sale products.

IN WooCommerce I have page that shows only product which is regular. So can anyone tell me how to do it.

Comment: Do you want to remove Add To Cart button and show only products data ?

Comment: I want to show all Products but don't want to show product which is on sale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to filter out the WITHOUT SALE products with the code below placed just above the `if ( have_posts() ) :`

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array( // Simple products type
            'key'           => '_sale_price',
            'value'         => 0,
            'compare'       => '=',
            'type'          => 'numeric'
        ),
        array( // Variable products type
            'key'           => '_min_variation_sale_price',
            'value'         => 0,
            'compare'       => '=',
            'type'          => 'numeric'
        )
    )
);
query_posts( $args );
```

The code is placed in a copy of `archive-product.php` which I renamed archive-product_withoutsale.php and made as a page template.

Comment: In 2023, this doesn't work for products which have never been on sale.

Answer (score 0):

#### In 2023 this works:

If the products aren't on sale, they don't have `_sale_price` meta_key in the database table `wp_postmeta`. You can use [meta_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/) to filter only products without `_sale_price`.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'     => '_sale_price',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ),
    ),
);


query_posts( $args );
```